# Check if current request is protected in Rails with CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I'm using the CanCan gem in my Rails app and want to check if the current request is a protected resource in my application.

So for example I have the following:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  load_and_authorize_resource

end
```

How can I check if the request is protected by CanCan?

I can access the controller and action via params. I can't use the standard `can?` and `cannot?` helpers as they will check if the `current_user` has permission rather than if the action itself has a protection on it.

So for example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :check_protected

  def check_protected
    if can? params[:action].to_sym, Object.const_get(params[:controller].classify)
      # resource is protected
    else
      # resource is not protected
    end
  end

end
```

^^ This won't work because it will always say `false` when no `current_user` or if the user doesn't have permission. **I need to check if the resource itself is protected with CanCan.**

If I had these examples:

```
class PostsController < AdminController

  def index
  end

end

class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end
```

The index for PostsController should be identifiable as protected, and the index for HomeController as unprotected.

Comment: CanCan is a user authorization gem, the purpose is to check if a user has access to an authorized resource.  It requires an ability class and current_user method to work.  You could override the defaults as explained [on this page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/changing-defaults).

Comment: @trueinViso I do have both an `Ability` class and `current_user` method. But I want to know if the current controller method has any cancan attributes attached to it.

Comment: The controller method doesn't have any cancan attributes attached to it.  The abilities are defined on the current_user.  When you say skip_authorize_resource that just means it won't check if the current_user has access to a resource.

Answer (score 1):

CanCan uses [CanCan::ControllerResource#skip?](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/bccdd70c57ca2b3bc8b60dc1ceac9ffcfb875630/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L48) method to determine whether it should authorize resource or not. So I guess you may rely on it as follows:

```
  def check_protected
    if CanCan::ControllerResource.new(self).skip?(:authorize)
      # resource is not protected
    else
      # resource is protected
    end
  end
```

I've tried it in my sandbox and it worked for me

Comment: Getting the error `uninitialized constant CanCan::ControllerResouce` so it always thinks the resource is protected.

Comment: syntax may wary depending on version of CanCan that you use

Comment: It's no longer complaining about the error, but it still returns false for everything even resources which have protection on them. For example `self` returns `#<Admin::DashboardController:0x007fa7da209228>` and Dashboard inherits from my AdminController which has the `load_and_authorize_resource`in it.

Comment: Well, `skip?` method *should* return `false` for protected resources

Comment: That's correct. But it returns false for controllers which don't inherit from `AdminController` and don't have `load_and_authorize_resource` in them or any parent controllers.

Comment: See updated post for examples. The first should return false when I hit its index and the second true when I hits index.

Comment: **In short... it's also returning false for not protected resources.**

Comment: I believe it's because the HomeController doesn't have any skips in it or rather any reference to CanCan in it or its parent controllers. Perhaps also need to check if the controller has CanCan attached to it at all?

Comment: This is hard because controller has only two methods related to cancan - `cancan_resource_class` and `cancan_skipper`. And both are always present in controller no matter if it is attached to CanCan or not. Atm I don't see any way to perform this without forking CanCan

Comment: One hack was to add `skip_authorize_resource` to the HomeController, but it requires adding to every controller as trying to add it to a parent for all unprotected controllers doesn't work, so it's pretty nasty.